# use multiple results of a query within the query with joins

Tags: mysql

I have some tables in my database, three main ones and one that holds the many-to-many relations.

```
1. Student (student_id, student_name)
2. Sport (sport_id, sport_name)
3. Departm (depart_id, depart_name) 
4. Sch (sch_id, sch_name)
5. StudSport(relationid, studendid, sportid, departid, schid)
```

What I want to do is e.g. retrieve the name of the department based on the relations when I know the id. I can get the ids like this:

```
SELECT departid, schid from studsport 
inner join Student on student_id = studentid 
inner join Sport on sport_id = sportid
where student_id = 1 and sport_id=2
```

but I want to get the names of the department and the Sch from their corresponding tables, and I dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't select anything from Student or Sport, you can remove the corresponding inner joins.

```
SELECT d.depart_name, sch.sch_name FROM StudSport s
INNER JOIN Sch sch ON s.schid = sch.sch_id
INNER JOIN Departm d ON s.departid = d.depart_id
WHERE s.studendid = 1 AND s.sportid = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this???

```
select sch.sch_nam, departm.depart_name,

-- what you have already --

Left outer Join StudSport on Student.student_id = Studsport.studentid and Sport.sport_id = StudSport.sportid
left outer Join Sch on StudSport.schid = Sch.sch_id
left outer join Departm on studsport.depart_id = studsport.departid
```

This is untested, a fiddle makes it much easier to give answers because of that.

EDIT - I misread your original query - before the downvotes start to rain - fixing it right now.

The way you should use LEFT OUTER and INNER joins is how the data is meant (again, a fiddle will normally be usefull) but it's just a couple of joins from what you have i guess:

```
select *

from studsport
join student on studsport.studentid = student.student_id
join sport on studsport.sportid = sport.sport_id
left outer Join Sch on StudSport.schid = Sch.sch_id
left outer join Departm on studsport.depart_id = studsport.departid

where student_id = 1 and sport_id=2
```

Comment: ooh yes left outer joins, I will give this a try, thank you!